# How to obtain The Oracle Package name from a Crystal Report file using .NET code

Tags: .net, oracle, crystal-reports

I'm trying to obtain the Oracle package name used for a Crystal report data source using .NET code.
I have obtained the procedure name, but for some reason I can not find the package name.

```
     Dim rpt as new ReportDocument
     rpt.Load(filename)

     Dim procedureName As String = rpt.Database.Tables.Item(0).Location 
     Dim DataSourceAliasName As String = rpt.Database.Tables.Item(0).Name
```

Currently using .NET Crystal Decisions version: 10.5.3700.0

Comment: This question is specific to the Crystal API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QualifiedName attribute is not exposed on the public dotnet wrapper.  You have to access the non-public underlying COM object and use that.

You need to reference the following DLLs:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel
```

Below is an example code snippet.  Note that it will come back prefixed with the schema name.  I ended up chopping that off in my real implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         ReportDocument doc = null;
         CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table = null;
         PropertyInfo prop = null;
         ISCRTable rasTable = null;

         doc = new ReportDocument();
         doc.Load("c:\\workspace\\temp\\example.rpt");
         table = doc.Database.Tables[0];

         prop = table.GetType().GetProperty("RasTable",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
         rasTable = (ISCRTable)prop.GetValue(table, null);

         Console.Out.WriteLine(table.Name);    
         Console.Out.WriteLine(rasTable.QualifiedName);

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a break point, and viewing the contents of rpt.Database.Tables.Item(0)?

Update:  Here is a list of some properties: [Crystal Reports](http://www.webtropy.com/articles/type.asp?o=CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine)